# Warning: lazy: Expected the result of a dynamic import() call when your code is as in documentation

Tags: reactjs

The question and answer is based on https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2193 but I think it will be helpful to have it on StackOverflow too.

If you coded something similar to the code from React.lazy docs:

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
const OtherComponent = lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <OtherComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

you may get the following error:

> Warning: lazy: Expected the result of a dynamic import() call. Instead
> received: function OtherComponent() {}
> Your code should look like: const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('./MyComponent'))

But hold on! Your code already looks like `const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('./MyComponent'))`!

Answer (score 4):

The question and answer is based on https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2193 but I think it will be helpful to have it on StackOverflow too.

### The answer from the article:

A quick solution is to wrap native import, which gets transformed by Parcel, in your own Promise which would return Harmony module-like result, like so:

```
const OtherComponent = lazy(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  import('./OtherComponent')
    .then(result => resolve(result.default ? result : { default: result }))
    .catch(reject);
}));
```

### Solution for classes:

Your classes should be written with keyword `default`:

```
export default class Foo extends Component {}
```

### Solution for functional components

They should be exported as default:

```
const MovieDetails = () => {}
export default MovieDetails;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I updated my component to export as a default and that fixed the issue. Is it possible to NOT export as default and still allow for lazy imports?

Comment: @CWSites I suppose the first proposed option from the article should do this.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes than I can give. It is an amazingly simple solution. I was having trouble loading my remotes in my host routing file, but switching from a named export to a default export was all that was needed. Other solutions suggested a package to handle imports, which is unnecessary with this approach.